# How to create 3D mesh using extracted LiDAR points in as.mesh3d function from rgl package in R

Tags: r, 3d, point-clouds, rgl, lidar

I am trying to create a 3D mesh of a specific building from points that I extracted from a lidar point cloud. I then created a matrix from the x, y and z values to feed into the as.mesh3d function from the rlg package and since its from a lidar survey, I have 27,000+ points for this one building. I run into an error when I try to create the mesh. I've copied in a sample of 20 points from the point cloud:

```
X <- c(1566328,1566328,1566328,1566328,1566328,1566327,1566327,1566327,
         1566327,1566327,1566327,1566327,1566327,1566327,1566327,1566327,
         1566326,1566326,1566326,1566326)
Y <- c(5180937,5180937,5180936,5180935,5180936,5180937,5180937,5180936,
         5180936,5180935,5180935,5180935,5180936,5180936,5180937,5180938,
         5180938,5180937,5180936,5180936)
Z <- c(19.92300028,19.98300046,19.93700046,19.88099962,19.93500046,19.99500046,    
         20.00400046,20.00600046,19.97199962,19.92499962,19.95400046,
         19.99099991,20.01199991,19.97600020,19.95800008,19.93200008,
         19.95300008,19.94800008,19.94300020,19.98399991)
#created a matrix
xyz <- matrix(c(X, Y, Z), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)
```

The problem arises when I try to create the mesh using as.mesh3d():

```
mesh <- as.mesh3d(xyz, y = NULL, Z = NULL, type = "triangle", col = "red")
```

This is what I get: `Error in as.mesh3d.default(xyz, y = NULL, Z = NULL, type = "triangle",  :  Wrong number of vertices`

The same error happens for the original dataset of 27000+ points despite all being of the same length.

I'm really not advanced in R and was hoping I could get some advice or solutions on how to get past this.

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

The `as.mesh3d` function assumes the points are already organized as triangles.  Since you're giving it 20 points, that's not possible:  it needs a multiple of 3 points.

There's a problem with your calculation of `xyz`:  you say `byrow = TRUE`, but you're specifying values by column.  Using

```
xyz <- cbind(X, Y, Z)
```

would work.

If I plot all of your points using `text3d(xyz, text=1:20)`, it looks as though there are a lot of repeats.

There are several ways to triangulate those points, but they depend on assumptions about the surface.  For example, if you know there is only one Z value for each (X, Y) pair, you could use `as.mesh3d.deldir` (see the help page) to triangulate.  Here's the code and output for your sample:

```
dxyz <- deldir::deldir(X - mean(X), Y - mean(Y), z = Z)
# Warning message:
# In deldir::deldir(X - mean(X), Y - mean(Y), z = Z) :
#   There were different z "weights" corresponding to
# duplicated points.
persp3d(dxyz, col = "red")
```

[image: snapshot]

I had to subtract the means from `X` and `Y` because rounding errors caused it to look very bad without that:  `rgl` does a lot of things in single precision, which only gives 7 or 8 decimal place accuracy.